# scrollTo and scrollIntoView don't working

Tags: javascript, scrollview

I've trying to apply a smooth scroll on my page when user click on nav menu (internal links).
I could create a link between the nav menu and the section on page and it works well, but when I try to apply the method  scrollIntoView to make a smooth effect, this one doesn't works. See my code below:

```
function initScrollSuave() {
  const linksInternos = document.querySelectorAll('.js-menu a[href^="#"]');

  function scrollToSection(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const href = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("href");
    const section = document.querySelector(href);

    section.scrollIntoView({
      block: "start",
      behavior: "smooth",
    });
  }

  linksInternos.forEach((link) => {
    link.addEventListener("Click", scrollToSection);
  });
}

initScrollSuave();
```

Someone could help me with it? I've tried to apply the scrollTo() but looks like it doesn't work too.
I'm using Chrome browser.

```
function scrollToSection(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const href = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("href");
    const section = document.querySelector(href);
    const topo = section.offsetTop;

    window.scrollTo({
      top: topo,
      behavior: "smooth",
    });

    /*
    section.scrollIntoView({
      block: "start",
      behavior: "smooth",
    });*/
    
  }

  linksInternos.forEach((link) => {
    link.addEventListener("Click", scrollToSection);
  });
}

initScrollSuave();ype here
```

Comment: Hi! Can you set up a jsfiddle for this?  Including the HTML you're running this code against?

Comment: Hi @JohnFu. **jsfiddle**? What for? It's against [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  rules.